# Evaluating formulas passed on the command line

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, argparse

I have a small(ish) python script that I used to plot csv delimited data, using matplotlib and pandas (the CSV is read into a pandas dataframe). Basically reinventing a poor version of gnuplot.

A typical invocation to plot csv data emitted on stdout by the process `makes_csv` goes like:

```
makes_csv | plot.py --cols 1 3
```

which means "plot columns 1 and 3 of the input, as separate series, against column 0 (with the headers coming from the input data)".

Now, I would like to add the ability to plot a *derived* column, which is a formula referring to one or more existing columns. E.g., I might write something like:

```
... | plot.py --formula-cols 'foo=col(1)/col(3)*100'
```

which would mean: plot the (per-element) result of dividing the value in column 1 by the corresponding value in column 3, times 100, and call this series "foo".

I don't need the exact syntax above - the main things I want are basic mathematical functions and the ability to refer to columns. I don't want to reinvent the wheel parsing formulas or use a third-party formula parsing: I'd like to use some python native way.

I'm not concerned about security - if a malicious formula can delete my hard-drive or wreck my credit, I'm OK with that: I'm entering these formulas myself and don't care about sandboxing.

Comment: You may need to quote the `foo` argument, just to make sure the shell doesn't do anything funny with special characters of spaces.  With respect to `argparse`, you'll just get a string value.  e.g. `args.foo="col(1)....".  `eval(args.foo)` might do what you want, but start with the simple and obvious cases.  Code up something like this, and come back with a new question when/if you hit problems.  At this point your question is a bit open ended.

Comment: @hpaulj - thanks, I quoted the foo argument to avoid it being interpreted by the shell.

Answer (score 1):

The answer would probably involve the built in functions `eval()` and/or `exec()`. But it's hard to answer more specifically without knowing how 'plot.py' works.  For example, your example expression would need to be able to create a new column 'Foo'.  It also needs to access the current columns, but we don't know how are the columns are stored in plot.py?

Here's a gist of one way to do it:

```
# csv data stored in a list of rows
data = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [2, 4, 6],
    [3, 6, 9]
]

# formula from the command line argument
formula = 'row[0]/row[2]*100'

source = f'''
for row in data:
    row.append({formula})
'''

exec(src)
```

`source` is code for a loop that appends to value of the formula to each row in the data table.  `exec()` executes the code.  Without additional arguments, `exec()` uses the current scope.  So, `data` refers to the global list `data` and `row[0]` in the formula refers to the first element of the loop variable `row`.

Modifying this example code to work with the data structures in plot.py is left as an exercise for the reader.

**Edit: Added this after reviewing code on github.**

Because plot.py uses pandas to process the csv files, this can be fairly easy.  Just enter a pandas formula on the command line and use `exec()` in the script to execute it.  For example:

```
# example DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A':[1, 2, 3, 4],
    'B':[5, 6, 7, 8],
    'C':[9, 0, 1, 2]
})

# formula from the command line 
formula = "df['D'] = (df['A'] + df['C']) / df['B']"

# apply the formula
exec(formula)

# result
    A   B   C   e
0   1   5   9   2.000000
1   2   6   0   0.333333
2   3   7   1   0.571429
3   4   8   2   0.750000
```

Note: the "formula" can be any valid python/pandas code.

Comment: Thanks RootTwo. You are right that I should have included a stripped down version of my plotting program, but it was a bit more complex than I wanted to include in the question. Here's a [github link](https://github.com/travisdowns/robsize/blob/master/plot-csv.py) and I'll update the question at some point with a smaller version.

Comment: Based on the code at the github link, I added an example of how to do it using pandas.